# how to check many to many table for duplicates thru Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For example, take the following database tables: Students, Courses, and StudentsCourses.

How do I, in Entity Framework, make sure when adding a new course for a student, that the course doesn't already exist? Which means to me, checking StudentCourses table.

Do I need to write straight sql to check that?

Comment: you mean something like `StudentsCourses.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId && x.CourseId == courseId)` ??

Comment: But the StudentsCourses isn't available in the navigation properties.

Comment: Well you instantiate the context then query the context, as per the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a simple many to many relationship, you may not have a `StudentsCourse` entity. I like this pattern for adding to a many to many relationship:

```
public Student
{
   private _Courses = new List<Course>();

   public int ID { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection Courses 
   {
      get { return _Courses; }
      protected set { _Courses = value; }
   }

   public void AddCourse(Course course)
   {
      //And you can add your duplicate check here
      if(!Courses.Any(c => c.ID == course.ID))
         Courses.Add(course);
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the `Courses` property is not a read-only collection so it doesn't prevent someone bypassing that method elsewhere with:

`student.Courses.Add(course);`

But then the methods suggested in the other answers don't prevent that either

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var context = new StudentContext()
{
 var alreadyExists = context.StudentsCourses.Any(x => x.StudentId == studentId && x.CourseId == courseId);
}
```

Comment: I did instantiate the data context MyDBEntities object but there is not a StudentsCourses object that I can query against. I'm pretty new at this so I maybe misunderstanding, apologies. I can do stuff with Students and I can do stuff with Courses.

Comment: Did you add the StudentsCourses table onto the designer or through code first or not at all? you will need this table.

Comment: I used the database to create the designer (not code first). By default it only shows Students and Courses on the designer. If I click on the link it shows they are connected via StudentsCourses but that table doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method:

```
public bool IsStudentOnCourse(int studentId, int courseId)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext()) //replace for real context..
    {
        return db.StudentsCourses.Any(x => x.StudentId == studentId && x.CourseId == courseId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

BenjaminPaul's answer works very wel. Another option is to try and retrieve your student, and if it does not exist, create a new one.

You could create a method like this

```
public StudentCourse CreateOrUpdate(VM_StudentCourse studentCourse)
{
    StudentCourse dbStudentCourse;
    using (var context = new StudentContext()
    {
        dbStudentCourse = context.StudentsCourses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StudentId == studentCourse.studentId && x.CourseId == studentCourse.courseId);
        If (dbStudentCourse == null)
        {
           dbStudent = new StudentCourse();
           dbStudent.StudentId = studentCourse.StudentId;
           dbStudent.CourseId = studentCourse.CourseId;
           context.Add(dbStudent);
        }
        dbStudent.OtherProperty1 = studentCourse.SomeProp;
        dbStudent.OtherProperty2 = studentCourse.SomeOtherProp;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return dbStudentCourse;
}
```